# Sonar build does not run Cucumber tests

Tags: cucumber, sonarqube

I am trying to run Sonar build on Jenkins. My project contains both Junit and Cucumber tests. I verified the log files after build, the Sonar build kicks off after normal maven build and picks only the Junit tests but not Cucumber tests.

I have the following versions and plugins available in my POM file. Please let me know if any one has come across the similar issue and fixed it. Many Thanks!

Junit version 4.11
Cucumber version 1.1.2
Sonar version 3.5.1

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-jetty</id>
                    <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                        <daemon>true</daemon>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-jetty</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <configuration>
                <stopPort>8999</stopPort>
                <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
                <connectors>
                    <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                        <port>8997</port>
                        <maxIdleTime>3600000</maxIdleTime>
                    </connector>
                </connectors>
                <systemProperties>
                    <systemProperty>
                        <name>dqs.env</name>
                        <value>local</value>
                    </systemProperty>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>                
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*RunDQSWsTest.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>none</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*RunDQSWsTest.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

RunDQSWsTest.java is the main file which runs all the .feature files

Comment: After removing the maven-surefire-plugin from POM file, Sonar is able to pick the cucumber tests, but all the Assertion statements are failing.

Comment: SonarQube doesn't yet support import of Cucumber tests reports. See https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-2854