# SONAR not reporting cucumber test results

Tags: junit, sonarqube, cucumber

My maven project is trying to use SONARqube through Jenkins for test coverage report.
We are able to see the test coverage for testcases that use Junits; but for those which are covered using Cucumber/gherkin, we are unable to see the coverage report. Sonarqube is not even taking that code into account.we see only 11% as complete coverage whereas we clearly know that the coverage till now will be definitely more than that.
I tried googling around and found the some answers to be in the following two links, but none of them giving me better clarity if getting cucumber results in sonarqube can be achieved now.
I found another link where somebody had commented that cucumber report can never be done in SONAR, but that was something commented in the year 2013.
So totally unsure as what to be done here. Please guilde.

Note: Gherkin plugin is already installed in SONARqube.

[Sonar build does not run Cucumber tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658973/sonar-build-does-not-run-cucumber-tests)
[Sonar / JaCoCo4sbt / Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083605/sonar-jacoco4sbt-jenkins)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sonarqube + Cucumber + Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38621818/sonarqube-cucumber-gradle)